# Unique copy of std::shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11

I have an object (let's call it X) that is accessible by other object by the means of `std::shared_ptr`. However at some point in the on of these objects need to create an unique, non-shared copy of X because it wants to modify it. This is somehow similar to copy-on-write, but not exactly the same due to some other details.

Basically I would like to have such semantics:

```
struct Foo
{
  std::shared_ptr<Bar> bar;
  void go()
  {
    // bar.use_count() >= 1
    bar.make_this_object_unique();
    // bar.use_count() == 1
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you just mean `bar = std::make_shared<Bar>(*bar);`, to give a (unique) shared pointer to a new object copied from the old one? Or did I miss something?

Comment: @MikeSeymour he can't do that because then there would be two shared_ptr instances watching the same pointer.  Either of them might delete the resource.

Comment: how will you invalidate the other shared pointers that are holding this resource?

Comment: @sbaker: No there wouldn't. `make_shared` will create a new object, copying the old one, and return a shared pointer to that. Existing pointers will still manage the old object.

Comment: Sorry @MikeSeymour, you're right.  I need to read things more closely - I thought I read shared_ptr, not make_shared.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you simply want to copy the object, and get a shared pointer to the new object, then that's

```
bar = std::make_shared<Bar>(*bar);
```

This assumes that `Bar` is the actual type of the target. If you want to copy arbitrary subclasses of `Bar`, then you'll need a virtual function to copy the object, for example:

```
struct Bar {
    virtual std::shared_ptr<Bar> clone() = 0;
};

struct SomeKindOfBar : Bar {
    virtual std::shared_ptr<Bar> clone() {
        return std::make_shared<SomeKindOfBar>(*this);
    }
};

bar = bar->clone();
```

You might want to test `bar.unique()` to determine whether the copy is necessary.

Comment: Thanks. This is somehow different than semantics with pre-C++11 pointer classes I've been using so far, but seems reasonable.

Comment: One last thing - how can I avoid copying the object if it is unique already?

Answer (score 2):

Not possible in the general case. May be possible in two cases:

1. The object stored in bar is of Bar type and not of a class inherited from Bar. Then just use the copy constructor (provided it is available):

   `bar = std::make_shared<Bar>(*bar);`
2. Bar or any of its base classes provides clone functionality in the form of virtual function creating newly allocated copy:

   `bar = std::shared_ptr<Bar>(bar->Clone());`

Answer (score 2):

```
template<typename T>
std::shared_ptr<T>& cow_ptr( std::shared_ptr<T>& t ) {
  if (t && !t.unique())
    t = std::make_shared<T>( *t );
  return t;
}
```

gives you copy-on-write for `T`.  This will slice `t` if it is not actually a `T`.

Use is:

```
struct Foo
{
  std::shared_ptr<Bar> bar;
  void go()
  {
    cow_ptr(bar);
  }
}
```

you can even use it directly, like `cow_ptr(bar)->blah()`.

`cow` stands for "copy on write".  `cow_ptr` stands for "moo".

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

```
bar = shared_ptr<Bar>(new Bar(*bar));
```

You need to do is perform a proper copy on the underlying object because having two shared_ptr instances managing the same memory isn't going to work.